# Hive Double and Decimal value incorrect format

Tags: pyspark, hive, hiveql, greenplum

I am migrating the sql statement greenplum to HiveSQL supported with pyspark scripts. we are encounter the issues if the double or decimal value, the value getting changed while doing the sum of the double or decimal value.

source data output as below like.

```
+------------------------+
|        test_amount|
+------------------------+
| 6.987713783438851E8    |
| 1.42712398248124E10    |
| 6.808514167337805E8    |
| 1.5215888908771296E10  |
```

actual greenplum provide the output while doing the sum of the amount value as below like,

```
2022-01-16  2   14970011203.1514433
2022-01-17  2   15896793850.6107666
```

GP sum out put

```
+-------------+------+------------------------+
|     _c0     | _c1  |          _c2           |
+-------------+------+------------------------+
| 2022-01-16  | 2    | 1.4970011203156286E10  |
| 2022-01-17  | 2    | 1.5896740325505075E10  |
+-------------+------+------------------------+
```

please help us.

Comment: Hive double data gives you approx value and decimal gives you exact value. So, you will get always different values than original. Here is more details on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70164000/issue-float-data-type-in-hive/70167187#70167187